# Find multiple tags with condition

Tags: beautifulsoup

Is it possible to find multiple tags with a condition?

```
<a href = "/img/something.jpg">
<img src= "/img/somethingelse.png">
```

Could I say

Find all "a" and "img" tags containing "/img/"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just supply function (can be lambda function) to `find_all()` method:

```
data = """<a href = "/img/something.jpg">
<img src= "/img/somethingelse.png">"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.body.find_all(lambda t: t.name in ('a', 'img') and \
                         ('href' in t.attrs and '/img/' in t['href']) or
                         ('src' in t.attrs and '/img/' in t['src'])):
    print(tag.name, tag.attrs)
    print('*' * 80)
```

Outputs:

```
a {'href': '/img/something.jpg'}
********************************************************************************
img {'src': '/img/somethingelse.png'}
********************************************************************************
```